# How to understand incoming constraints in flutter?

Tags: flutter

The [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) says

> Containers with no children try to be as big as possible unless the
> incoming constraints are unbounded

And

> Otherwise, the widget has a child but no height, no width, no
> constraints, and no alignment, and the Container passes the
> constraints from the parent to the child and sizes itself to match the
> child.

In my understanding, **The word "incoming constraints" means the "constraints from the parent" ,**

**Question 1**:I have search the source code of Container Class , It will have a constraints variable only , and seems not the place for store incoming constraints, So **where is the incoming constraints stored in widget** ?

**Question 2**: How do I know a widget will pass the incoming constraints ( which it got from its parent ) to its child  or not in layout ? Or there is no general rule, I need to check the doc for every widget to know how it behave?

Comment: incoming constraints are set by a parent, more here: [Understanding constraints](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints)

Comment: @pskink does every widget will set the incoming constraints for its child? because from the container doc , the will only passes the constraints from the parent to the child based on some conditions

Comment: check the link i posted above, it has nice 29 examples explaining constraints (full source code provided, so you can run them on your device)